# Longest Sub Array

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone suggest a simple solution for the below question.

> **Longest Sub-array**: Find the length of longest contiguous sub-array where the sum of the elements in subarray is less than or equal to "k".

Inputs are: `array` and `k`.

Example:

```
Array = {1,2,3}, k = 3
```

Output:

> 2

Explanation:

> Sub arrays : {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3}
>
> {1,2} => max length = 2;  1+2 = 3 (<=k);

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. You want to find the maximum possible value of something which is less than or equal to `k`? That sounds too trivial to code, because it would be `k` itself.

Comment: Are you trying to find a subarray whose _length_ is _k_, or one whose _sum_ is _k_ ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Edited the question now.

Comment: Find minimum element and add it to sub-array, then remove it from array. Repeat until the `sum` of sub-array is larger than `k`. I think this is a simple solution.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh: It has to be a contiguous sub-array, not just any subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient method is to use dynamic programming, to reduce the number of summation operations. For example, if you sum (1 + 2) = 3, you don't wanna sum (1 + 2 + 3) = 6 again, you only wanna sum (3 + 3) = 6 (where the first 3 has already been calculated and saved into a hashmap). In this solution, the hashmap represents the sum from index `i` to index `j`, in the format `<i, <j, sum>>`. So you have all sums starting from index `i` stored in the inner hashmap. Note that you could also use a 2D array instead of the nested hashmap structure, but for very large data, you are likely to get an out-of-memory exception while initializing that array.

```
    static int maxLength(int[] a, int k) {
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>();

        int maxLength = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            Map<Integer, Long> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
            map2.put(i, (long)a[i]);
            map.put(i, map2);
            if(a[i] == k) {
                maxLength = 1;
            }
        }

        for(int l = 2; l <= a.length; l++) {
            long sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i <= a.length - l; i++) {
                int j = i + l - 1;
                Map<Integer, Long> map2 = map.get(i);
                sum = map2.get(j - 1) + a[j];
                map2.put(j, sum);

                if(sum <= k) {
                    if(l > maxLength) {
                        maxLength = l;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return maxLength;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and naive answer is to traverse your array and find the longest subarray starting at the current index.

```
int[] a = { 1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,3 };
int k = 4;

int best_i = 0; // from index
int best_j = 0; // to index, so best length = j - i + 1
int best_sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // starting index from beginning to end 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) { // ending index from current to end
        sum += a[j];
        if (sum > k) break;
        if (j - i > best_j - best_i) { // best length found
            best_i = i;
            best_j = j;
            best_sum = sum;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("best length = " + (best_j - best_i + 1) + " (indexes " + best_i + ".." + best_j + "), sum = " + best_sum);
// best length = 3 (indexes 3..5), sum = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

an O(n) approach.  In high level:

Have 2 pointers `start` and `end`, `start` being the start of subarray, `end` being end (exclusive).  An int `sum` to keep the subarray sum. An int `len` to keep subarray len.

Have both set to position 0.

1. Keep moving the `end` pointer by:

   ```
   while (end < arr.length && sum + arr[end] <= k) {
       sum += arr[end];
       end ++;
   }
   if ((end - start) > len ) {
     len = (end-start);
   }
   ```

   Which will find you the longest subarray with `sum < k` with start with `start`
2. Move `start`

   ```
   sum -= arr[start];
   start++;
   ```
3. Go back to 1, until `end` passed the last element of array

At the end you will find the max length (stored in `len`)

Leave handling of some edge-cases to you (e.g. if there is an element in array with value `> k`. etc)

Comment: I have personally wrote little piece of code to verify and this logic should be fine.  The function is less than 25 lines, it shouldn't be difficult to implement by yourself.  Given this is obviously some kind of exercise/homework, I won't post the code.

Comment: I just finished this challenge, I have taken a similar approach. But I don't think it's better than brute force approach with a for loop within a for loop. Start pointer is working like an outer for loop. Posting my code as well.

Comment: @Manish No. I guess you missed the point here.  It is surely better than brute force ( O(n) vs O(n^2) ).  Give a second look: the `end` pointer never goes back.  So this algorithm move both `start` and `end` pointers only forward.  Of course it has some assumption in place, like the values in array is only positive.

Comment: thanks for explaining, but will not step 3 will act as another outer for loop? Your approach is certainly better, sum operation will happen only 2n times, and seems linear.

Comment: @Manish yes it is a outer loop. But having a outer loop does not necessary mean it is a O(n^2) algorithm. If you like you can write the above logic in one single loop, though less readable imho

Answer (score 0):

Python Implementation

Time complexity `O(n)`

No additional space needed

```
def longest_sub_array_sum(input_array: list, k: int) -> int:
    longest_size = 0
    
    if input_array:
        i = 0
        j = 1
        longest_size = 0 if input_array[i] != k else 1
        current_sum = input_array[i]
        
        while j < len(input_array):
            if current_sum <= k:
                if j - i > longest_size:
                    longest_size = j - i
                current_sum += input_array[j]
                j += 1

            elif current_sum > k:
                current_sum -= input_array[i]
                i += 1
                
    return longest_size
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I am using only on for loop, but I have my doubt on the complexity of this solution, is it O(n) or O(n2). Seems like one for loop but I don't think a number of operation are less than brute force or two for loop.

function maxLength(a, k) {

```
var maxLen = 0;
var currMaxLen = 0;
var currSum = 0;
var currIndex = 0;

for(index = 0; index < a.length; index++){
    currSum = currSum + a[index];

    if(currSum <= k){
        currMaxLen++;
    } else{
        //reset
        index = currIndex;
        currIndex++;
        maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, currMaxLen);
        currSum = 0;
        currMaxLen = 0;
    }
}
maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, currMaxLen);
return maxLen;
```

}

Comment: 1. It is not Java (as what you asked in question) 2. It is fundamentally the same as brute force using nested for-loop: you are resetting `index=currIndex` (I'd rather call it `end` and `start` instead) when you increment the currIndex, for which only save you from some looping from a very-naive brute-force implementation. (break early when you encountered sub-array that passed the end of array)

Comment: So, an extreme case: if you have an array `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100]` and you want to find for `k = 1`, it should be obvious for you to find out it is a `O(n^2)` algorithm